# TinyMCE custom dropdown set value with checkbox

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE text editor.I added custom dropdown menu button into the  toolbox. In this custom menu button I want to load dynamic value with checkboxes.

I create a array which return the value with checkbox. The code is-

```
  $scope.customerList = ['Customer 1','Customer 2'];

  var menuItems = [];
  $scope.customerList.forEach(function(customer, index){

    var thisCheckbox  = "<input type='checkbox' value='"+customer+"' />";
      item = {
          'text': thisCheckbox
      };
      menuItems.push(item);
  });
```

The array of menuItems it return value with checkbox, like this,

[image]

Then I added this menuItems in Tinymce toolbox -

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    plugins: 'link image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code | customDrpdwn',
    setup: function(editor){
        editor.addButton( 'customDrpdwn', {
            text : 'Customers List',
            type: 'menubutton',
            icon : false,
            menu: menuItems
        });
    }
};
```

It shows into the dropdown, like this, [image]

It didn't get the checkbox with value. How can I solve this issue.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE does not support adding items to menus or toolbar buttons in the way you are trying to use checkboxes - it does however support selectable options in both Menus and Toolbar Buttons.

- Look at the `visualblocks` plugin for examples of how to add selectable items to a Menu.
- Look at the `advlist` plugin for examples of how to add selectable items to a Toolbar Button.
- Look in the main `tinymce.js` file for how it implements the `fontsizeselect` toolbar option (also a selectable Toolbar Button).

These examples should give you what you need to implement selectable options.